# Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type

Tags: c#, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package and want to include a script which checks if a file exist before retrieving the file and saving that data to a table.

I have three separate variable that I have set up:

`fileExistFlag      Int32       0`

`fileName       String      check.txt`

`folderPath     String      C:\`

My C# code looks like this, where I am checking:

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here
    String fp = Dts.Variables["User::folderPath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::fileName"].Value.ToString();
    if (File.Exists(fp))
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::fileExistFlag"].Value = 1;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(fp);
    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::fileExistFlag"].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

When I try to compile my script, I receive the following error:

`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables` for all four instances.

How can I solve the issue?

Updated code:

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_04f6fa3ba49a4ddeac3d3d7fc29f04f2.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            String fp = Dts.Variables.Get("User::folderPath").Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables.Get("User::fileName").Value.ToString();
            if (File.Exists(fp))
            {
                Dts.Variables.Get("User::fileExistFlag").Value = 1;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(fp);
            MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables.Get("User::fileExistFlag").Value.ToString());
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
    public static Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable Get(
        this Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables variables, string name)
    {
        foreach(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable item in variables)
        {
            if(item.Name == name) return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Odd... it seems to be there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.item.aspx

Comment: There's no need to write that code. Using the ForEach (file) Enumerator will pull all the files that match an existing pattern. If no file is found, assuming you have a Data Flow Task inside the container, it's not going to run it. I suspect you have something slightly off in the code, I'll verify once I get to the office

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly, this indexer [*does seem to exist*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.item.aspx). If it isn't working, though, you might be able to use an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable Get(
        this Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables variables, string name)
    {
        foreach(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable item in variables)
        {
            if(item.Name == name) return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and use:

```
... Dts.Variables.Get("User::folderPath").Value ...
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am brand new to SSIS scripting so having some issue. I have changed my code to reflect your answer and now I am getting two errors. First is, `Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptObjectModel.Variables' cannot be used like a method`, and second is, `The type of namespace name 'Variable' could not be found`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge explicit full type names added

Comment: I modified your code (hope it is okay) to make all the error go away but I am presented with another error, `Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class`... Any idea?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge that (adding an "s") wasn't quite the right fix; have edited; as for the other: **do what it says** (I'll edit that in too)

Comment: I updated my question with the way my code is right now. Please let me know what to fix.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge just move that free-floating method inside of a class, as shown above

Comment: So put it outside `main` but inside the `public partial class`?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge no, the `static class` goes *inside* the `namespace`, but **outside** of the `public partial class`.

Comment: Thank you and now the script is not throwing any error. I am having an issue when I run the SSIS package but I will open another question and link it here. Only fair you get credit for what I asked in my question title which is working.

Comment: I will write the error here and open the new question: `Error: 0x1 at Script Task: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ST_04f6fa3ba49a4ddeac3d3d7fc29f04f2.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge that *probably* just means that `Get` is returning `null`, because there is no matching variable. Can you debug it and step through?

Comment: I copied and pasted the variable that I created in my SSIS package with the variable in my script.

Comment: I finally fixed it... Because I am using the custom function, I had to remove the `User::` and just keep the string. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 14):

This is a known BUG in SQL Server BIDS 2005/2008 after installing side by side a later version of SSIS. For example if you are developing a SSIS 2008 package and then install SSIS 2012.

A **workaround** is to move the file *"Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll"* located in the path:
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies"* to a backup folder, then the bids take the reference from the path *"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\"*

But it doesn't seem to work for all the cases reported.

Source:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/744390/ssis-any-pre-2012-error-cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-microsoft-sqlserver-dts-runtime-variables

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938608/en-us

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did exactly that and it also helped solve my issue.

Comment: +1 Just had the same issue and this worked for me. The accepted answer didn't. It complained about `Runtime` in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables`

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10 with a side-by-side install of SQL 2014.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 7 with a side by side installation of SQL 2008 and SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Use Browse in the add references window and look for this dll: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll